# Resize the canvas onclick button

Tags: css, html5-canvas

What I want to achieve click on the zoom out button change the height width of canvas. But canvas height width aren't changing. Problem is CSS is inline and dynamically added.

HTML

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '#zoom-in', function() {

  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1];
  console.log(canvas);
  canvas.width = 1200;
  canvas.height = 600;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 300;
  canvas.style.width = '800px !important';
  canvas.style.height = '600px !important'

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fpd-view-stage" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px; position: 
relative; user-select: none;">

  <canvas class="lower-canvas" width="1200" height="600" style="position: 
  absolute; width: 1200px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: 
  none; user-select: none;"></canvas>

  <canvas class="upper-canvas " width="1200" height="600" style="position: 
  absolute; width: 1200px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: 
  none; user-select: none; cursor: pointer;"></canvas>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="zoom-in">Zoom in</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="zoom-out">Zoom out</a>

</div>
```

Site link for better understanding how canvas added [link](http://arf.hopenotout.pk/test.php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSS styling to resize canvas. set `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` for width and height respectively .

***DEMO***

```js
$(document).on('click', '#zoom-in', function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[1];
  //var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.width = 400;
  canvas.height = 300;
});
```

```css
.lower-canvas{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.upper-canvas{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fpd-view-stage" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px; position: 
relative; user-select: none;">

  <canvas class="lower-canvas" width="1200" height="600" style="position: 
  absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: 
  none; user-select: none;"></canvas>

  <canvas class="upper-canvas " width="1200" height="600" style="position: 
  absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; touch-action: 
  none; user-select: none; cursor: pointer;"></canvas>

</div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="zoom-in">Zoom in</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="zoom-out">Zoom out</a>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but this cannot work on my site. You visit my site ??

Comment: @Adam, you are using fabricjs to zoom the canvas?

Comment: So what can i do remove this js

Comment: @Adam you need to use `setzoom()` for zoom-out, as you are using that to zoom-in.

Comment: I didnot get you setzoom. How i use it